# Why Android Custom font taking too much time?

Tags: android, custom-font, timedelay

F1! i am working on another activity of android app and in this activity i applied custom font in 8 text views in urdu language, but it take 12 to 15 seconds for displaying this activity and if i remove custom font then it take 1-2 seconds for displaying this activity with by-default font but by-default android urdu language font is not pretty good. Remember that i never used any activity of font in .xml file. Any idea ?

My Java code:

```
public class JismPics extends Activity {
    TextView txtView;
@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.jism_pics);

    txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textResult);
    Typeface myCustomFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/noori.ttf");
    txtView.setTypeface(myCustomFont);

  }
}
```

Comment: i have updated my post, check now.

Answer (score 0):

I use custom font in many of the apps I develope and never have that problem. Maybe you can override the views so you don't have to change the font on the `onCreate()` method

Something like this:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView
{

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/NeoSans.otf");
        this.setTypeface(font);
    }

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/NeoSans.otf");
        this.setTypeface(font);
    }
public MyTextView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/NeoSans.otf");
        this.setTypeface(font);
    }

}
```

Don't forget to call your custom class on the layout.

```
<com.myproject.util.guicomponents.MyTextView
                  android:id="@+id/txt_name"
                  android:textSize="22sp"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:text="@string/txt_reg_name"                             
                  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                  />
```

Comment: But whats the difference, can i make another class for this font?
me also using same method as like you but i declare it onCreate() method.

Comment: El_Mochiq: i applied by using constructor method but it crash my application.